# Transform 2 Scala Spark Dataframes and a Long value into a single JSON string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a 3 objects in a scala/spark data pipeline. 2 are dataframes and 1 is a Long value.

I need to create a single json object which includes the 3 objects.

For example if passing a particular date to the application api as a request:

```
val df1 = getDF_1(date)
val df2 = getDF_2(date)
val value_3 = getValue_3(date)
```

Individually I can convert these into json but I'm strugging a lot to create a single JSON response like:

```
response = {"date":date, "values"{
                                  "df1":{nested json report}
                                  "df2":{nested json report}
                                  "long3":23234
                                 }
             }
```

This is how the dataframes are being created:

```
case class IpAccessCount(ip:String, uri:String, accessCount:Long)
    def toIpAccessCount(ip:String, uri:String, accessCount:Long): IpAccessCount = IpAccessCount(ip, uri,accessCount)
    val ipAccessCount=udf(toIpAccessCount _)
    spark.udf.register("ipAccessCount", ipAccessCount)
    
    val ipAccessCountByDate = spark.sql("""select ip, uri, datetime, count(*) as accessCount from csvData group by ip, uri, datetime """)
    ipAccessCountByDate.createOrReplaceTempView("ipAccessCountByDate")
    def GetDateIpAccessCount(date_as_str:String)= 
    ipAccessCountByDate.filter(col("datetime")===s"$date_as_str").drop("datetime").map(r => toIpAccessCount(r.getString(0), r.getString(1), r.getLong(2))).toDF().coalesce(1)
```

I have no idea how to merge them into a single json response.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no idea why you wanted to do this, but you can convert the dataframe to json individually and create a final json manually, But I still do not recommend this is your datafeame are big.

Comment: It's part of a project and this is the requirement. The Dataframes arent that big, the csvs they are taken from are split in to 4 or 5 csvs of around 20mb. How would you create the json manually?

Comment: Does your df1 and df2 have single record or multiple records?

Comment: The DFs hold multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution if you really have to implement this way.

```
val df1 = "[" + getDF_1(date).toJSON.collect().mkString(",") + "]"
val df2 = "[" + getDF_2(date).toJSON.collect().mkString(",") + "]"
val value_3 = getValue_3(date)

val json_response = s"""
      |{"date":"${date}", "values":{
      |                                  "df1":"${df1}",
      |                                  "df2":"${df2}",
      |                                  "long3":23234
      |                                 }
      |             }
      |""".stripMargin
```

Explanation: Lets create JSON array string of both df1 and df2. Then append df1, df2, date as a json string in json_response, you may convert this string to JSON object if needed.

Note: If you have huge data in df1 or df2, as you're doing collect(), you might end up have out of memory Exception.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess that the collect has to happen before a JSON string can be created.